# 'Integer out of range' error while deleting hidden slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using the following code to delete all hidden slides in my .pptm presentation. It has 254 slides.

```
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

However, I am getting an error that integer is from 1 To 154 alone and that 155 is beyond its range.

Can someone please explain?

Is the new value of `ActivePresentation.Slides.Count` taken when `Next i` is run?

Thank you.

Comment: Your upperbound doesn't change. However, Slides(Uppebound and nearby slides) are deleted. The error occurs when the loop tries to access your upperbound (and nearby slides).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that after some of the slides are deleted, some indexes *at the end* become no longer available but your loop is trying to access them anyway (because the upper bound of the for loop doesn't change).

To get around this problem, run the loop in reverse:

```
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Alternatively, you may use a `Do...While` loop like this:

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Do While i <= ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
```